# Multiple button with Single Tableview

Tags: swift

any one help me to solve this issues

I have multiple Button in my view ...when i click the button i need to call the same table with multiple array...how can i do that here i have to use the only one table any one help to solve this issues

Thanks in advance

here is my code

```
    @IBAction func CountrySelectDropDown(_ sender: Any) {

            if(CountryBoolean == false){
                self.Popup_view.isHidden = false
                CountryBoolean = true
                StateBoolean = false
                CityBoolean = false
                self.tableview.reloadData()

            }
            else{
                self.Popup_view.isHidden = true
                CountryBoolean = false
            }

        }

        @IBAction func State_DropDwon_Touch(_ sender: Any) {

            if(StateBoolean == true){
                self.Popup_view.isHidden = false
                CountryBoolean = false
                StateBoolean = true
                CityBoolean = false
                self.tableview.reloadData()

            }
            else{
                self.Popup_view.isHidden = true
                StateBoolean = false
            }

        }


        @IBAction func City_DropDown_Touch(_ sender: Any) {

            if(CityBoolean == true){
                self.Popup_view.isHidden = false
                CountryBoolean = false
                StateBoolean = false
                CityBoolean = true
                self.tableview.reloadData()

            }
            else{
                self.Popup_view.isHidden = true
                CityBoolean = false
            }

        }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of items in the sample data structure.

        var count:Int?

        if(CountryBoolean == false) {
            count = CoutryArray.count
        }

        if(StateBoolean == true) {
            count =  StateArray.count

        }

        if(CityBoolean == true) {

            if (self.resultSearchController.isActive) {
                return self.filteredTableData.count
            }
            else {
                return self.reponseArray.count
            }
        }


        return count!

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell?
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)


        if(CountryBoolean == false) {

            cell?.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            cell?.layer.borderColor =  UIColor(red:223/255.0, green:44/255.0, blue:51/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            cell?.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Avenir", size:13)
            var CountryDict = CoutryArray[indexPath.row]

            cell!.textLabel!.text = CountryDict["countryName"] as? String



        }

        if(StateBoolean == true) {

                        var StateDict = StateArray[indexPath.row]
                        cell!.textLabel!.text = StateDict["name"] as? String


        }
}
```

Comment: Without studying it too closely you seem to have the right idea. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the response i edit my question here i said i have multiple button when click the button i am showing the tableview...here i have to use same table with mutiple button select